# NodeJs TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i want to create a cloud function which sends email if some data where added to my database. Unfortunately while trying to deploy my function i receive this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Here is my function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const postmarkTransport = require('nodemailer-postmark-transport')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

// 2. Admin SDK can only be initialized once
try {admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)} catch(e) {
    console.log('dbCompaniesOnUpdate initializeApp failure')
 }

// 3. Google Cloud environment variable used:

const postmarkKey = functions.config().postmark.key
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(postmarkTransport({
auth: {
         apiKey: postmarkKey
}
  }))


 // // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase- 
 functions
//

exports.sendingEmailForlocationsRequests = 
 functions.database.ref('/clubs/{clubId}/{pushId}')
.onWrite((event) => {
//I want to retrieve the pushID        


return sendEmail();
})

    function sendEmail() {
    // 5. Send welcome email to new users
    const mailOptions = {
            from: '"Dave" <noreply@clate.de>',
            to: 'locations@clate.de',
            subject: 'Welcome!',
            html: `<Test>`
    }
    // 6. Process the sending of this email via nodemailer
    return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
            .then(() => console.log('dbCompaniesOnUpdate:Welcome 
    confirmation email'))
            .catch((error) => console.error('There was an error while 
    sending the email:', error))
    }
```

Comment: In which part you get the error?

Comment: Here's a [working script/example](https://hightechtele.com/articles/firestore-trigger-email) for Firestore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like 'postmark' isn't set in your firebase configuration. You can set what's retrieved by functions.config() using the CLI: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Comment: could you explain it more in detail?

Comment: it looks like the code comes from a tutorial, I'd imagine you skipped a step that set the environment variables. Retrace the steps and make sure you didn't miss anything...